# Decomposing a Vector Space into a direct sum of Generalized Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I've seen a proof that doesn't involve any induction, but now I am trying to do this inductively since it is bothering me.

If $T$ is a linear operator over a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and the characteristic polynomial $\phi(t)$ of $T$ factors into 
\begin{gather}
\phi(t) = \prod^n_{i = 1}(t - \lambda_i)^{m_i}
\end{gather}
where each $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$ Then for each generalized eigenspace $K_{\lambda_i}$ we have that 
\begin{gather}
V = \bigoplus^n_{i = 1}K_{\lambda_i}.
\end{gather}
 My idea was to use a base case of two eigenvalues. Our base case will show that when $\phi(t) = (t - \lambda_1)^{m_1}(t - \lambda_2)^{m_2}$ we have that. If we consider $f(t) = (t - \lambda_1)^{m_1}, g(t) = (t - \lambda_2)^{m_2},$ we see that the following comes from the fact that $f,g$ are both co-prime. We have that 
\begin{gather}
V = N(f(t)) \oplus R(f(t)).
\end{gather}
Additionally, we note that $N(f(t)) = K_{\lambda_1}$ and we have that $R(f(t)) = N(g(t)) = K_{\lambda_2}.$ So we have that 
\begin{gather}
V = K_{\lambda_1} \oplus K_{\lambda_2}.
\end{gather}
So, this is where I am not sure where to continue. I don't know what to suppose as my inductive hypothesis. My ultimate goal is to express the final polynomial 
\begin{gather}
\phi(t) = (t - \lambda_1)^{m_1} \cdots (t - \lambda_n)^{m_n}.
\end{gather}
we can express one polynomial as $f(t) = (t - \lambda_1)^{m_1}$ and $g(t) = (t - \lambda_2)^{m_2} \cdots (t - \lambda_n)^{m_n}.$ Then with the discussion above argue that 
\begin{gather}
R(f(t)) = \bigoplus^n_{i = 2} K_{\lambda_i}.
\end{gather}
and then we will have that $V$ is a direct sum of these generalized eigenspaces. But I am not sure what the inductive step here is.

Comment: My feeling here is that you would start with/show $V=K_{\lambda_{1}}\oplus S$,  for some $S$ and then proceed to decompose $S$ .